# Use cases for Google Prediction API

Tags: google-prediction

Has anyone here been using the Google Prediction API? For what? Did it "work"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're looking for a real-world case check out this one which [automatically assigns priority to bugs](http://illcom.posterous.com/hp-quality-center-defect-priority-prediction).

I've also created a couple test projects to get a feel for how I might use it in production.

One of them [suggests tags](http://www.developmentsample.com/tagsuggest/) for Stackoverflow questions.  The model for this was trained with questions (from the data dump) that only had 1 tag.  This helps it recognize particulars of a specific tag.  Code and prose were split into separate features, as one of them may have greater impact on the result.  When given a question, it returns the top 10 tag suggestions; actual tags are included for comparison.

Structure was a CSV file:

```
"tag","code blocks(200 chars)","body text(200 chars)"
```

Some characters were filtered out of `code` that caused training errors: `[]^|~`.  Not sure which of those was causing problems.

If you'd like to see a certain question added to the test list, let me know.  Obviously, questions that have code predict better.

The other project predicts [movie ratings](http://www.developmentsample.com/movierater/) based on IMDB data and director/actors.  Unlike the tag suggester, this one is live so you can experiment with different combinations to see what it would predict.

Structure here was:

```
rating,"directorId","actorId actorId actorId"
```

Both are running on Google App Engine so python is the back end.  I'm not using a particular API; just followed some of Nick Johnson's [example code](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Trying-out-the-new-Prediction-API).

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted to see!

Comment: Unfortunately the links in the answer are no longer online. Anyone have some updated examples?

Answer (score 3):

I have not used this API. But their [website lists](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/) the below usecases

- Recommendation systems (demo code)
- Spam detection (demo code)
- Customer sentiment analysis
- Upsell opportunity analysis
- Message routing decisions
- Diagnostics
- Document and email classification
- Suspicious activity identification
- Churn analysis
- Language identification

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm mostly interested in what non-Googlers have used it for/how they did it (ie, which language/library, how they handled data collection, how they structured the data etc).